# SQL: Select query without nested query

Tags: sql, nested

I have next input data, 
There are two tables

```
create table Courses(
id number(19) not null,
name varchar(100),
);

create table Students (
id number (19) not null,
name varchar(100),
course_id number (19) not null,
);
```

I need to write query for get all cources with count of student for example more than 10
So, I've written variant with nested query like this

```
select distinct courses.name from student, courses where courses.id=student.courses_id and (select count(Students.id) from Students where student.course_id = course.id)  > 10
```

!!! Didn't test, just wrote for this post, it is example!!!
So, My question is how to write the same query without nested query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT courses.name /*, COUNT(*)*/
FROM student JOIN courses ON courses.id = student.courses_id
GROUP BY courses.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with

```
Select c.name, count(s.id) as StudentsCount from Courses c join stundets S on c.id = s.course_id group by c.name having count(s.id) > 10
```